# Error: Cannot find module '../config/conf.json'

Tags: javascript, mysql, server

I am new to JS and I want to open this project which I found on GitHub but there was a problem of this kind, as I understand there is no conf.json file
But I can't create it myself, what will they write there?
Here is a link to the project https://github.com/natahiko/Taxiconn

No idea what to do with this config file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this simply create a file called `conf.json` inside conf folder and put a simple empty object inside.

```
cat conf.json
{}
```

Solve the rest of the errors(add missing fields based on the errors) and you should be good to go.